# AngularJS - Pass JSON object data from clicked ng-repeat item to new item-specific state/view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json

I've tried using stateparams to pass data for a clicked item in an ng-repeat list to a new view showing a list of details / the data for this item (employee), which I've been able to do, but only for top-level data properties, and not for data in a sub-array of these items.

How else, apart from using stateparams, which I'm not sure is even the right method for doing this, can I do this so that data like the following can be displayed in the new state/view, including details for each of the employee's payments, which I want to repeat in a table?

employeesService:

```
app.service('employeesService', function() {

    var employees = [
    {
        id: '21101994',
        icon: 'img/icon.png',
        iconAlt: 'N C Image',
        title: 'Mr',
        firstName: 'N',
        lastName: 'C',
        dateOfBirth: '21/10/1994',
        niNumber: 'JZ123456D',
        jobTitle: 'Web Developer',
        department: 'Development',
        joinDate: '18/04/2017',
        leaveDate: '18/04/2017',
        email: 'example@mail.com',
        phonePrimary: '07123 456789',
        phoneSecondary: '07123 456789',
        menu: 'ncMenu',
        employeePayments: [
            {
                id: 1,
                code: 'TEST',
                paymentType: '',
                hours: '',
                zeroiseHours: false,
                partPay: false,
                rate: '',
                employerPercentage: '',
                pay: '',
                paidPer: '',
                fromDate: '',
                sequence: '',
                employerPension: '',
                csaReference: '',
                suspend: false,
                netToGross: false,
                requiredTotal: '',
                paidToDate: '',
                protectedNet: '',
                arrearsCarried: ''
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                code: 'TEST',
                paymentType: '',
                hours: '',
                zeroiseHours: false,
                partPay: false,
                rate: '',
                employerPercentage: '',
                pay: '',
                paidPer: '',
                fromDate: '',
                sequence: '',
                employerPension: '',
                csaReference: '',
                suspend: false,
                netToGross: false,
                requiredTotal: '',
                paidToDate: '',
                protectedNet: '',
                arrearsCarried: ''
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        id: '1',
        icon: '',
        iconAlt: 'Employee 2 Image',
        title: 'Mr',
        firstName: 'A',
        lastName: 'Z',
        dateOfBirth: '01/01/2000',
        niNumber: 'JZ123456D',
        jobTitle: 'Job Title',
        department: 'Testing',
        joinDate: '01/01/2017',
        leaveDate: '01/01/2017',
        email: 'example@mail.com',
        phonePrimary: '07000 123456',
        phoneSecondary: '0151 123456',
        menu: 'employee2Menu'
    },
]

var getEmployees = function() {
    return employees;
}

return {
    getEmployees: getEmployees
}
```

-

Current state for employee details (click location where I want to pass data to):

```
.state('employees/employeeDetails', {
        url: '/employees/employeeDetails/:employeeId/:icon/:iconAlt/:title/:firstName/:lastName/:dateOfBirth/:niNumber/:jobTitle/:department/:joinDate/:leaveDate/:email/:phonePrimary/:phoneSecondary/:employeePayments',
        templateUrl: 'pages/employees/employeeDetails.html',
        params: {
            employeeId: null,
            icon: null,
            iconAlt: null,
            title: null,
            firstName: null,
            lastName: null,
            dateOfBirth: null,
            niNumber: null,
            jobTitle: null,
            department: null,
            joinDate: null,
            leaveDate: null,
            email: null,
            phonePrimary: null,
            phoneSecondary: null,
            employeePayments: null
        },
        controller: 'employeeDetailsController'
    })
```

-

employeeDetailsController:

```
app.controller('employeeDetailsController', function($scope, $state, $stateParams, $document, employeesService) {
$scope.employeeId = $stateParams.employeeId;
$scope.icon = $stateParams.icon;
$scope.iconAlt = $stateParams.iconAlt;
$scope.title = $stateParams.title;
$scope.firstName = $stateParams.firstName;
$scope.lastName = $stateParams.lastName;
$scope.dateOfBirth = $stateParams.dateOfBirth;
$scope.niNumber = $stateParams.niNumber;
$scope.jobTitle = $stateParams.jobTitle;
$scope.department = $stateParams.department;
$scope.joinDate = $stateParams.joinDate;
$scope.leaveDate = $stateParams.leaveDate;
$scope.email = $stateParams.email;
$scope.phonePrimary = $stateParams.phonePrimary;
$scope.phoneSecondary = $stateParams.phoneSecondary;
$scope.employeePayments = $stateParams.employeePayments;
```

Comment: Why not just pass an id and then retrieve the object by querying the array? Eventually your url will become too long depending on data length and its amount..

Comment: This is exactly what I'm asking how to do

Comment: I AM ASKING HOW TO DO THIS

Comment: Yes... I'm not sure what you're getting at. You suggested using a shared service instead, but in the question I wanted to know HOW I would use a shared service with this data to pass the object

Comment: Sorry it was unclear what exactly you're trying to do, also no need to use caps like this, your question was very unclear what exactly you're trying to achieve as you might notices there are numerous ways to achieve the result. None the less I corrected my mistake and posted my answer below.

Comment: what version of UI router are you using @Nick

Comment: version 1.0 for angular 1.x

Answer (score 0):

In your ng-repeat add ng-href with following path (note the id binding form ng-repeat item).

```
<div ng-repeat="item in employees">
    <a ng-href="/ViewEmployee/{{item.id}}">View Profile</a>
</div>
```

Your router, you need to add the path from above, ViewEmployee will now expect an id as a parameter (/ViewEmployee/123 for example).

```
.when("/ViewEmployee/:id", {
    templateUrl: "views/viewemployee.html",
    controller: "EmployeePreviewController"
})
```

Then in your controller, inject $routeParams to retrieve the id from the router.
Then you will need to retrieve the array of employees from your service, iterate each value and check if the id matches the one in $routeParams, based on the example above it would be 123.

If the record exists in the array, add the object to the $scope.EmployeeRecord model

```
app.controller('employeeDetailsController', function($scope, $routeParams, employeesService) {
   var employees = employeesService.getEmployees();
   $scope.EmployeeRecord = {};

    for (var i = 0, i < employees.length; i++) {
        if(employees[i].id == $routeParams.id){
            $scope.EmployeeRecord = employees[i];
        }
    }
});
```

Your view now has a model called EmployeeRecord with data populated when id is found.

```
<div>{{EmployeeRecord.title}}</div>
<div>{{EmployeeRecord.jobTitle}}</div>
```

Comment: I've tried implementing this using ui-router, which, as you can see from my original post, is what I've used for routing the app, and the u-sref location for the link is not working. No cursor change and no redirection